# size element based on another element's dimensions in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Say I have an element like this:

```
export default class DemoAxis extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      const el = findDOMNode(this);

      this.dimensions = getDimensionsFromNode(el);      
    }

  render() {
    const style = {
      parent: {border: "1px solid #ccc", margin: "2%", maxWidth: "40%", padding: 10}
    };

    return (
      <div ref="line">
        <svg style={style} width={this.dimensions.width} height={this.dimensions.height}
```

I want to size the `svg` element based on the dimensions of the line element.

The element's dimensions will only be available in `componentDidMount` which is called after render.

I know I can call `setState` but that will cause a re-render and that might give me UI issues.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [react-dimensions](https://github.com/digidem/react-dimensions)

Wraps a react component and adds properties containerHeight and containerWidth. Useful for responsive design. Properties update on window resize. Note that the parent element must have either a height or a width, or nothing will be rendered

```
// ES2015
import React from 'react'
import Dimensions from 'react-dimensions'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() (
    <div
      containerWidth={this.props.containerWidth}
      containerHeight={this.props.containerHeight}
    >
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dimensions()(MyComponent) // Enhanced component
```